# Not navigating from one page to another page in Xamarin.Forms while using using Xamarin.Essentials shake detect event

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two class MainPage.xaml and Home.xaml. I have written Home.xaml using Xamarin.Essentials shake detect code and want to move from Home to MainPage.xaml but it is not working.

**Home.xaml.cs**

```
namespace StarRatingApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Home : ContentPage
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            Accelerometer.ShakeDetected += Accelerometer_ShakeDetected;

            Accelerometer.Start(SensorSpeed.Game);
        }


        private void Accelerometer_ShakeDetected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            });
        }  
    }
```

What am I doing wrong in **Accelerometer_ShakeDetected** method ??

Answer (score 0):

You are not navigating in the method. You just create a new NavigationPage. And this won't do anything. You have to tell the system, where you want to navigate and how.

You have two options:

1) Navigate to your page (this adds the page to the Navigation-Stack)

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
```

or 2) Overwrite your mainpage with the new NavigationPage (this removes the whole NavigationStack and starts a "new" navigation)

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

You can find more infos about navigation in the documentation >> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical